# Serilog custom log level names

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I'm aware that when logging with serilog, log level names (`Verbose`, `Debug`, `Information`, `Warning` etc) can either be left with their full name, or truncated to an either upper or lowercase representation by doing something similar to `{Level:u3}` - but how can I completely change the level names?

For example, I may want the level names to be in a different language to match the rest of my application.

Or, in my particular case, I find that the level "full names" are too big, but that having all level names with a specific length makes it much harder to identify messages of a different level when quickly scrolling through a log.

So I'd like to instead have:

- `VERBOSE`
- `DBG`
- `INFO`
- `WARNING`
- `*EXCEPTION*`
- `**FATAL**`

But I'm not sure how to accomplish this. How can this be achieved in `serilog`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I modify Serilog Log Levels to match up with Log4Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629436/how-do-i-modify-serilog-log-levels-to-match-up-with-log4net)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom formatter with Serilog and there write the messages with their levels as you wish.

https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output

The `ITextFormatter` may be better for what you need:
https://stackify.com/serilog-tutorial-net-logging/

Answer (score 1):

You make an Enricher to map the level to the string you want, then you reference the field it adds in the `outputTemplate`

However, you're better off using the `:u3` or another stable length rendering (or do something like `{LogLevel,10:u}` to make the column fixed width)